# MySql Join Query Problem

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update all transaction_subcategory_id's in transaction to match_subcategory_id in match where match_name in match is the same as transaction_subcategory_name in transaction.

Its got to be simple, just not getting very far with it...

this is our latest attempt...

```
UPDATE transaction JOIN match ON match.match_name = transaction.transaction_name
SET transaction.transaction_subcategory_id = match.match_subcategory_id;
```

tables

```
match
--------------------------
match_id
match_name
match_subcategory_id

transaction
--------------------------
transaction_id
transaction_name
transaction_subcategory_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `transaction` SET `transaction`.`transaction_subcategory_id` = `match`.`match_subcategory_id`
JOIN `match` ON `match`.`match_name` = `transaction`.transaction_name;
```

Just switch the position of the `SET` and the `JOIN` and it should work.

[MySQL Docs on UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

The docs only show the implicit join:

```
UPDATE `transaction`, `match` SET `transaction`.`transaction_subcategory_id` = `match`.`match_subcategory_id`
WHERE `match`.`match_name` = `transaction`.`transaction_name`;
```

But they say you can use any `JOIN` syntax that works on `SELECT` on `UPDATE`, so your query should work when switching `SET` and `JOIN`.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN match ON match.match_name = transaction.transaction_name' at line 2

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match SET transaction.transaction_subcategory_id = match.match_subcategory_id W' at line 1

Comment: Yes, match is a reserved word. Have to enclose it in backticks @user611468 Edited the query.

Answer (score 0):

try with SET before JOIN on your query